# Render a menu block in current user's language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, navigation

I have a multi-language site.

How this is supposed to work is that on /fr pages, everything except main navigation block should be in French. However, main navigation menu block should be in whatever currently logged user's language.

I tried to change language code in custom module using block or menu hook, but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom module for this.

Drupal can have seperate language detection for interface (menu item/interface elements) and content.  There was a [bug that was fixed recently](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2189267) so make sure you are on the latest 8.6.x version.

Assuming you have enabled all 4 core language modules and you have enabled at least 1 extra language than configure the **language detection methods** to accomplish what you want as I its outlined below.

Go to `Configuration > Regional and language > Languages > Detection and selection` and

- enable **Account administration pages**. This will allow each user to choose their preferred interface language (there will be a new option when they edit their profile page)
  [image]
- enable content language detection. This will make available the `language switcher (content)`) block.
- enable 1 detection method.  In my case I choose url (i.e. /en /fr) but you can choose any other or more methods if you like.

**ΝΟΤΕ:** The detection methods take precedence as they appear from top to bottom provided they are also enabled.

[image]

Go to `Structure > Block layout` and enable `language switcher (content)` (not `language switcher (interface text)`

Now lets say a user has chosen English as their `interface language` they can press on the `language switcher (content)` and their interface (menu, admin menu etc) will always  stay English.